# Mysterious line beneath the last row in a table

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently making a site in wordpress and stumbled upon something weird. A have a table with the opening hours of the store and there is a small gray line beneath the last row that I cant find anywhere in the code or in the CSS.

Ive used the developer mode of firefox to try and find it multiple times but I just can't find it.

I really want to remove this gray line.
Does anyone know wether this is some kind of bug or wether im blind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your current code for `<table>` in your style.css file

```
table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* line-height: 2; */
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

simply remove the `border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;` line or change it to this.

```
table {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* line-height: 2; */
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Incredible, I dont know how I missed that or why it didn't show up in dev mode but thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, I recommend using Google Chrome's Inspect Element tool. It's amazing for pointing out little issues like that.